# How to keep the ColorPicker swatch open all the time with Flash AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want the ColorPicker popup swatch to always stay open.

```
var cp:ColorPicker = new ColorPicker();
cp.open();
```

works fine but when focus is lost the window closes.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

The flash [default color picker](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/ColorPicker.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on which ColorPicker you are using. ( i mean who wrote it ).

But this one works as you need: http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2347

**Update**

Then you need to create you own ColorPicker class which will extend the original ColorPicker:

```
package  
{
    import fl.controls.ColorPicker;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    /**
    * ...
    * @author Jevgenij Dmitrijev ( http://www.ifmi.lt )
    *
    * @created {2012.05.10 16:08}
    *
    */
    public class CustomColorPicker extends ColorPicker
    {
        var _allowHide:Boolean = false;

        public function CustomColorPicker() 
        {

        }

        override protected function onStageClick(event:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            //Simple example .
            if(_allowHide)
                super.onStageClick(event);
        }

        override protected function onSwatchClick(event:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            // since on click it is closing, ovveride the function
            // and super the over function, since it is the one
            // which changes the color.
            super.onSwatchOver(event)
        }

        override protected function onSwatchOver(event:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            // just ovveride it, so it would do nothing.
        }
    }
}
```

And then in you project use:

```
var colorPickerMC:CustomColorPicker = new CustomColorPicker ();
addChild(colorPickerMC);
```

Comment: I have a feeling the OP means [this color picker](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/ColorPicker.html).

Comment: my Flash or Flex can not find this component, that's why i was asking. :) i thought it is gone already...

Comment: Updated the answer! Please check.

Comment: Thank you. It works pretty good but when you select a color the swatch closes. Any suggestions?